# The olam-haba tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Right now [olam-haba-world-to-come](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/olam-haba-world-to-come) is about both "the Afterlife" and "the days of Mashiach". Is this a good *status quo* or not?

Comment: By "afterlife", you mean one's personal afterlife immediately following his death?

Comment: @msh210 That's what I was thinking about, but see the questions and judge for yourself.

Comment: I think [tag:messiah] should be used for the days of Mashiach, although it seems to be referring to Mashiach the person

Comment: @ba That sounds like an answer.

Comment: This depends. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: @SethJ Our tag scheme might be structured independent of any one person's hashkafa. Even if they are the same time, they might be different conceptually or have different aspects.

Answer (score 3):

My proposal:

We have enough questions about the messiah (the person, and fake ones, and the Josephite(?) one) that he can have his own tag.

And then another tag for the messianic era would be appropriate, perhaps also including questions about the future resurrection (but not questions about resurrection in general).

And a tag about resurrection (both the future general-populace one and resurrection in general).

And a tag for the personal afterlife (heaven and/or hell, if you will) awaiting us all when we die.

Names could be, perhaps: [messiah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/messiah) (already exists); [atid-lavo](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atid-lavo) or [eschatology](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eschatology); [resurrection-of-the-dead](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resurrection-of-the-dead) (already exists); and [heaven-hell](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heaven-hell) (to replace existing [heaven](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heaven)). All with good tag wikis. The existing tag [olam-haba-world-to-come](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/olam-haba-world-to-come) would be deprecated as ambiguous and its tag wiki would say to use [heaven-hell](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heaven-hell) or [atid-lavo](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atid-lavo)/[eschatology](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eschatology) as appropriate.

Comment: I vote for [tag:eschatology]

Comment: Shall we implement this?

Comment: (Sigh.) See also [tag:latid-lavo-future].

Comment: We also now have [tag:messianism] and [tag:messianic-redemption]